# 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-backplane

I am using SignalR 2.2.2
MVC 5
JQUERY 3.3.1

I have signalr working in the website, hub setup and can send data to clients.

I now want to make this scaleable using MsSql, but the following code does not work as it cannot find the method.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=dbSource; Catalog=SignalRtest;User=SignalRtest_App;password=";
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString);

            app.MapSignalR();
        }
```

But it cannot resolve the UseSqlServer to create the backplane.

Anyone know how to solve this? I assume I am simply missing a package?

Packages installed:

```
 <packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer

Comment: Thanks guys, missing the SqlServer package, I knew it would be simple enough. Thanks again!!